# Magento connect stuck while installing

Tags: magento, ubuntu-9.10

I am facing this problem while installing extensions, themes basically anything from magento connect.
When I enter the extension key and click install It just gets stuck and even when it says done and I try and go back on admin page it says "There are PEAR processes running.
If you will close the window or navigate away from the page, installation will be interrupted.
"
Has anyone faced this problem. I am working on ubuntu 9.1 and having magento 1.4. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried running PEAR from the command line? PS - You should try and mark some answers as accepted on your earlier questions.

Comment: Hi Ya I tried that. but nt worked

Comment: Try this [script][1] to see if your system is compliant with the requirement of Magento -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: Hi Boris,
I did that and got a congratulations message. Is there any other way of getting my magento connect work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on the same computer and access your instalation via localhost (or 127.0.0.1) it can lead to problems. You should edit your hosts file and add same fake address such as 
www.localhost.com 127.0.0.1

I believe this is because most browsers don't store cookies for localhost and I have had problems with magento because of this in the past.

Comment: Hi Omar I tried that but still no success. The Pear processes tend to stuck. I changed the hosts file and added 127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com and opened www.localhost.com/magento/index.php.admin and when it ried insalling an extension it gets stuck